# Data from 1 row to 3 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am slowly learning how to do some very basic routines in Excel VBA, but I dont know how to tackle this one.
How can I go from data in one row looking like this :

`11-Jun,27.3,28.3,12-Jun,27.2,28.3,13-Jun,26.7,28.4,14-Jun,26.7,28.4`

to 3 columns. 
First column with date, 2nd with first value, 3rd with the second value ?
Thanks

Comment: Is that one string in one cell?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: np. Are there are lot of lines to modify?

Comment: Just one, but lots of data in it. A year worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your data in A1.

This will loop the data back to the desired column based on if there is a remainder left after dividing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitData()

Dim i, rownum, colnum As Integer
Dim str As Variant

colnum = 1
rownum = 2

str = Split(Cells(1, 1).Value, ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(str)
    If i Mod 3 = 2 Then
        Cells(rownum, 3).Value = "'" & str(i)
    End If
    If i Mod 3 = 1 Then
        Cells(rownum, 2).Value = "'" & str(i)
    End If
    If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
        rownum = rownum + 1
        Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "'" & str(i)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked great ! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe something like this :

```
Sub test()
x = Split(Range("A1"), ",")
y = (UBound(x) + 1) / 3
P = 1
For i = 1 To y
For Z = 1 To 3
Cells(i + 3, Z).Value = x(P - 1)
P = P + 1
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked great ! Thank you so much.